# LWC defaulting a checkbox input as checked based on a condition?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

back again for some help.

I feel like this should be a really basic thing that I just can't seem to get to work.

I am loading some boolean values onclick of a button, and I'd like to default some checkboxes to checked if those are true.

Using

```
<template if:true={graValue}>
<lightning-input type="checkbox" label="(GRA)" onclick={handleEditRowSelection} value="GRA" checked ></lightning-input>
</template>

<template if:false={graValue}>
<lightning-input type="checkbox" label="(GRA)"  onclick={handleEditRowSelection} value="GRA"  ></lightning-input>
</template>
```

```
handleEditUser(event) {
    this.graValue = event.target.dataset.gra;
    this.rimValue = event.target.dataset.rim;
}
```

```
 <lightning-button
variant="brand-outline"
icon-name="utility:preview"
label="Edit User"
name={user.Contact__c}
data-gra={user.GRA__c}
data-rim={user.RIM__c}
```

Always seems to default to true, even when the GRA value is false in the console log from that row button. I'm kinda at a loss as to what to do here.

Previously I tried setting the checked property on the input to be based on the value but am running into the same issue here.

When graValue = false, the checkbox is still displayed as checked even though the template should be rendering the unchecked one.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Each property of dataset attribute is a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#javascript_access), so if `user.GRA__c` is `false` (boolean), when `graValue` is setted reading from `event.target.dataset.gra;` it will be `"false"` (string), which is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), that's why the checkbox is rendered as checked even when `user.GRA__c` is false.

In order to set `graValue` as a boolean you could change that line to:

```js
this.graValue = event.target.dataset.gra === 'true';
```

By the way, you don't need the two block with `if:true` and `if:false`, you could set checked value as:

```html
<lightning-input type="checkbox" label="(GRA)" onclick={handleEditRowSelection} value="GRA" checked={graValue} ></lightning-input>
```